# Reading values from properties file and returning it to a method

Tags: java, web-services

I have method which takes two parameters and returns three values from properties file when called.

I have written a sample code and its working. I just want to know is there any better way of doing this?

Below is the code:

```
    @WebService(serviceName = "HS_WebService")
    public class HS_Service 
    {    
        ResponseInfo rd5 = new ResponseInfo();

        @WebMethod(operationName = "initiateBatchProcess")
          public @WebResult(name = "Response") ArrayList initiateBatchProcess(@WebParam (name = "BatchID")int BatchId, @WebParam (name = "MPTRef")String MPTRef) throws Exception
          {
              return rd5.initiateBatchProcess();
          }
   }
```

Here is the other class which is reading the values from properties file and passing to the above method (`rd5.initiateBatchProcess();`)

```
public class ResponseInfo
{    
    static Properties props = new Properties();
    ArrayList list  = new ArrayList();
    public ArrayList initiateBatchProcess() throws Exception
    {
        props.load(ResponseInfo.class.getResourceAsStream("ResponseFields.properties"));
        String method1_status = props.getProperty("method1_status");
        String method1_comments = props.getProperty("method1_comments");
        list.add(method1_status);
        list.add(method1_comments);
        return list;
    }
```

I am using array list to achieve this. Is there any better way of doing this?

Comment: Personally I would create a POJO that has a 'status' and 'comments' fields and return that. Then, depending on what is calling your web service, I would serialize that POJO into json or xml, so that you can quickly see which field contains each value, like a self-documenting API. Your way will work fine for a simple use case, but if you started adding more fields, it would get very confusing. Just my opinion

Comment: Similarly, I have more number of methods which returns variable no. of values from properties file. So still POJO into json will work ?

Comment: could you please provide a simple example?